# Perform (part of) a static function on a specific thread

Tags: multithreading, swift

I have a function(be it a static function or totally unaffiliated one) and a specific thread

```
class AnyClass{
    static func foo(myThread: NSThread) {
        ....
        // I want this *blablabla* to be performed on myThread
        ....
    }
}
```

How can I make is happen?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use thread, use dispatch queue (Grand Central Dispatch) instead. See Apple's documentation on [Migrating away from threads](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ThreadMigration/ThreadMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH105-SW1).

A typical usage pattern for GCD is:

```
class AnyClass{
    static func foo(queue: dispatch_queue_t) {
        ....

        let group = dispatch_group_create();
        dispatch_group_enter(group) // tell the OS your group has started
        dispatch_group_async(group, queue) {
            // Do your things on a different queue
            ....
            dispatch_group_leave(group) // tell the OS your group has ended
        }

        // Do your other things on the original thread simultaneously
        ....

        dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER) // wait for the queue to finish

        // Do other things still
        ....
    }
}

// Calling the function
let queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
AnyClass.foo(queue)
```